# Slow Stock Update using MySQL INNER JOIN and LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: mysql, performance, file, csv, import

I have a PHP file running on Cronjob to automatically update our website stock from my supplier. The CSV file from my supplier is less than 10 MB and currently has around 300,000 lines. It's simply a CSV and is downloaded to my web server. The CSV layout is simply: SKU | Stock.

In our store we only have 1,200 products. However, the CSV from my supplier has 300,000 lines - since my supplier has 300,000 products.

It's working perfectly fine. It's matching the SKU and updating the stock. I have also used WHERE A.status = '1' so that it only updates the 1,200 enabled products and not all 300,000 products in our store. The rest of the products are just disabled.

I can't really understand why it's slow. It's taking about 15 minutes to update 1,200 products. Takes hours if i remove WHERE A.status = '1' to update all 300,000.

This is the script i have:-

```
    /* Create temp table if not exist and truncate if there's something */
mysqli_query($conn,"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `oc_product_temp_2` (
                      `sku` varchar(255) NOT NULL, INDEX (sku),
                      `stock` double(10,0) NOT NULL, INDEX (stock)
                    )");
mysqli_query($conn,"TRUNCATE oc_product_temp_2");
/* End of temp table create and truncate */

/* Load data from CSV into our temp table */
mysqli_query($conn,"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$csv_file."' 
                    INTO TABLE oc_product_temp_2
                    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
                    ENCLOSED BY '\"'
                    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
                    IGNORE 1 LINES
                    (sku,stock)
                    ");
/* End of CSV load data */

/* Do actual update of stock */
$update_query = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE oc_product A
                    INNER JOIN oc_product_temp_2 B USING (sku)
                    SET A.quantity = B.stock
                    WHERE A.status = '1'
                    ");
/* End of actual update of stock */
```

Comment: Do you have any indices setup?

Comment: Thanks Tim. I don't really understand what you mean. Could you run through / explain further please ? Where am i looking?

Comment: Do you have an index?

Comment: Yes - It's using the SKU to match and update stock for the product. I'm using OpenCart if that helps.

Comment: Check the MySQL engine of your database tables. If these are in MyISAM, change it to INNODB.

Comment: Thanks. Seems much better using InnoDB rather than MyISAM. However it still takes about 15 minutes in terms of speed for the 1,200 products.

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables.